# KH and Riemann integrals example

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I am looking for examples that demonstrate how the KH integral is more "powerful" than the Riemann integral (i.e. can integrate more functions than the Riemann integral). For example, $1/\sqrt{x}$ is not Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$, but is KH-integrable. However, this function can be handled easily as an improper integral. What would be examples of functions that are KH-integrable yet cannot be handled even as improper (Riemann) integrals?

Comment: It doesn't seem very different to the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

Comment: @reuns - what do you mean?

Comment: That the KH integral isn't so common, while you'll find many results about the Riemann-Stieltjes integral